# knexjs innerjoin returning columns

Tags: typescript, knex.js

Hello i have a 1: n relationship
and when looking for a relationship I want to take the relationship:

like this:

```
{
  id: '7e413f8d-2a07-4f2e-bbc9-eb8892948a03',
  departament_name: 'test',
  employee: {
  employee_id: 'a9c678bb-c274-4908-add0-34a856d2458e',
  matricula: '123',
  departament_id: '7e413f8d-2a07-4f2e-bbc9-eb8892948a03',
  first_name: 'test',
  last_name: 'test2'
  }
}
```

but i got this:

```
{
  id: '7e413f8d-2a07-4f2e-bbc9-eb8892948a03',
  departament_name: 'test',
  manager_id: 'a9c678bb-c274-4908-add0-34a856d2458e',
  employee_id: 'a9c678bb-c274-4908-add0-34a856d2458e',
  matricula: '123',
  departament_id: '7e413f8d-2a07-4f2e-bbc9-eb8892948a03',
  first_name: 'test',
  last_name: 'test2'
}
```

query:

```
const rawDepartament = await this.db
  .select([
    `${this.tableName}.id`,
    `${this.tableName}.departament_name`,
    `${this.tableName}.manager_id`,
    `employees.id as employee_id`,
    `employees.matricula`,
    `employees.departament_id`,
    `employees.first_name`,
    `employees.last_name`,
  ])
  .from<Departament>(this.tableName)
  .where({ departament_name })
  .innerJoin<Employee>(
    'employees',
    `${this.tableName}.manager_id`,
    'employees.id',
  )
  .first();
console.log(rawDepartament);
```

relations:

[image]

Could someone help me how I could format my querie result to something like typeorm returns?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the knexjs package specifically so there might be a shortcut, but you can always just reformat the results.

```
const {id, department_name, ...employee} = result;
const fixed = {id, department_name, employee};
```

That takes all properties other than `id` and `department_name` and puts them inside an `employee` property.